# Sass variables nested styling

Tags: html, sass, scss-mixins

I try to optimize my styling which does have repeated styles mostly

i have like this

```
.ds-input.ds--valid .ds-input__control:not(#specificity-issue),
.ds-select.ds--valid .ds-select__control:not(#specificity-issue) {
  border-color: var(--my-color);

  &:focus {
    border-color: var(--my-border-color);
  }
}
```

what i tried to make variables but nested variables gives wrong result

```
$dsSelectors: "ds-select, ds-input";

.#{$dsSelectors}.ds--valid.#{$dsSelectors}__control:not(#specificity-issue),
 {
        border-color: var(--my-color);
    
      &:focus {
        border-color: var(--my-border-color);
      }
}
```

do we have any easy and short syntax to fix this

at the end, expected css will look like this

```
.ds-select.ds--valid .ds-select__control:not(#specificity-issue), .ds-input.ds--valid .ds-input__control:not(#specificity-issue) {
    border-color: var(--my-border-color);
}
.ds-select.ds--valid .ds-select__control:not(#specificity-issue):focus, .ds-input.ds--valid .ds-input__control:not(#specificity-issue):focus {
    border-color: var(--my-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@each` can use for this purpose. More information and examples: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each

> The @each rule makes it easy to emit styles or evaluate code for each
> element of a list or each pair in a map. It’s great for repetitive
> styles that only have a few variations between them. It’s usually
> written

```
$classes: ds-select, ds-input;
@each $class in $classes {
    .#{$class}.ds--valid .#{$class}__control:not(#specificity-issue)
    {
        border-color: var(--my-color);        
        &:focus {
            border-color: var(--my-border-color);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit for marge styles:**

To marge selectors with the same content, `@function` can be used.

```
@function mixToList() {
    $list: ds-select, ds-input;
    $result: ();
    @each $a in $list {
        $result: append($result, ".#{$a}.ds--valid .#{$a}__control:not(#specificity-issue)", $separator: comma);
    }
    @return #{$result};
}

#{mixToList()} {
    border-color: var(--my-color);
    &:focus {
        border-color: var(--my-border-color);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is nice but the issue with this approach, it is repeating same styles with the selector, somehow would be nice to have selectors separated with , then our style, i think for this we need to use merge same group of selectors after build   `.ds-select.ds--valid .ds-
 .ds-select.ds--valid .ds-select__control:not(#specificity-issue):focus {
  border-color: var(--gco-color-accent);
}
 .ds-input.ds--valid .ds-input__control:not(#specificity-issue):focus {
  border-color: var(--gco-color-accent);
}`

Comment: Could you include the output (compiled CSS) that you want in the question?

Comment: just did that, thx

Comment: My answer is edited now.

Answer (score 0):

I make this function but result is bit different:

```
$classes: select, input;

@each $class in $classes {
    .ds {
         &#{-$class}&--valid &#{-$class} {
            &__control {
                &:not(#specificity-issue) {
                    border-color: var(--my-color);
                    
                    &:focus {
                        border-color: var(--my-border-color);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And result:

```
.ds-select.ds--valid .ds-select__control:not(#specificity-issue) {
     border-color: var(--my-color);
}
.ds-select.ds--valid .ds-select__control:not(#specificity-issue):focus {
     border-color: var(--my-border-color);
}
.ds-input.ds--valid .ds-input__control:not(#specificity-issue) {
     border-color: var(--my-color);
}
.ds-input.ds--valid .ds-input__control:not(#specificity-issue):focus {
     border-color: var(--my-border-color);
}
```